# scala TypedPipe switch columns

Tags: scala, scalding

I have a val in the format of `TypedPipe[(Long, Long)]`, how do I switch left and right columns around? More clearly, how to create a new val with left column as the value in the right column, the right columns with value populated in the left?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `map`:

```
val tp: TypedPipe[(Long, Long)] = ???

val pt: TypedPipe[(Long, Long)] = tp.map( x => (x._2, x._1) )
```